# How to migrate django users to firebase when the rounds are too high?

Tags: django, firebase, passwords, migration, sha

I'm looking to migrate users from Django to firebase, below is the code I'm using for testing.
The issue I'm facing is that it seems that the passwords have been hashed using 150k rounds when the firebase docs says the maximum is 120k for SHA256:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users#python

Is there an alternative?

Here is the error I get:

```
ValueError: rounds must not be larger than 120000.
```

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth, exceptions
from passlib.utils import to_bytes


server_path = ''
fb_credentials = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate(server_path + 'files/serviceAccount.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(fb_credentials)


old_hash = 'pbkdf2_sha256$150000$rsWX3Dbbd3K6$EYgXPBAz/Ero9PIgIFs/8pWGmGT+diTOQs1DZv4Ytjw='
email = 'user@gmail.com'

rounds = int(old_hash.split('$')[1])
salt = old_hash.split('$')[2]

users = [
    auth.ImportUserRecord(
        uid='70sSUptkmkN95QTFJ0gWduzdlpP1',
        email=email,
        password_hash=to_bytes(old_hash),
        password_salt=to_bytes(salt)
    ),
]

hash_alg = auth.UserImportHash.pbkdf2_sha256(rounds=rounds)
try:
    result = auth.import_users(users, hash_alg=hash_alg)
    for err in result.errors:
        print('Failed to import user:', err.reason)
except exceptions.FirebaseError as error:
    print('Error importing users:', error)
```

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Passwords aren't working after migration with 120000 rounds but firebase won't permit 150000 rounds.

Comment: Looks like there's a little more info here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/512